# Switch statement using Contains

Tags: apex

Trying to incorporate a statement on the switch but getting errors. Would like to utilize the switch statement .vs if/else. Am I missing something?

Compile Error: Expecting 'ELSE' but was: '(' at

> when (multiSelectValues.contains('NonStandardAuto')) {

```
Public Void updateLOBlistNew() {
   try { 
    multiSelectValues.clear();
    multiSelectValues.addAll(CCRA.Lines_of_Business__c.split(';'));
      System.debug('UPDATED LOBS ' + multiSelectValues);           
    switch on multiSelectValues {
      when (multiSelectValues.contains('NonStandardAuto')) {
       System.debug('CASE LOB FOUND NONSTDAUTO ');
      }  
      when (multiSelectValues.contains('General Liability')) {
       System.debug('CASE LOB FOUND GeneralLiability ');
      }  
      when else {
       System.debug('CASE NO LOB FOUND');
      }
    }    
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be implementing this incorrectly. If you refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) of switch/when, a switch statement works on an expression

> Apex provides a switch statement that tests whether an **expression** matches one of several values and branches accordingly.

```
switch on expression {
    when value1 {       // when block 1
        // code block 1
    }   
    when value2 {       // when block 2
        // code block 2
    }
    when value3 {       // when block 3
        // code block 3
    }
    when else {       // default block, optional
        // code block 4
    }
}
```

And by definition, an [expression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_understanding.htm) is:

> An expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations **that evaluates to a single value**.

In your case, you have a *list* as an expression which will not be accepted at the first place in a *switch* statement (it should throw a compile time error similar to -- List is not a valid switch expression type). Furthermore, the *when* blocks will always work exactly on a value that the expression evaluates to, and not on a boolean value.

---

In order to use this in your case, you will need to use the supported expression types for *switch*, which are as below:

> Apex switch statement expressions can be one of the following types.
>
> Integer
>
> Long
>
> sObject
>
> String
>
> Enum

Answer (score 4):

That's not how switch works. It matches on specific discrete values, not on conditions. What you're doing is best suited for if/else.

Review the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had reviewed the documentation and just so use to using this in other language case statements. Would be great to see this expanded to Boolean expressions.